# Why isn't a call command at each frame of disassemble except the last

Tags: c++, gdb, x86-64, disassembly, callstack

I'm analyzing a core post-mortem via disassemble output of gdb. I'm new to this, so I'm still growing in my understanding of what I'm looking at. One immediate confusion for me is that as I go between frames and look at disassemble output, I don't see callq commands as the command being run as I would expect for all the non-frame 0 frames. Shouldn't each frame leading up to frame 0 be calling a function?

```
(gdb) f 0
(gdb) disassemble
...
=> 0x0000000001b0af10 <+16>:    mov    (%rdi),%rdx
...
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) info registers rdi
rdi            0x0      0
```

Makes sense: the crash happened due to a null ptr dereference. Now lets go up a fame and see the disassemble output there:

```
(gdb) up
(gdb) disassemble
...
=> 0x0000000001b1c01b <+315>:   test   %al,%al
...
```

What? The frame above is running test? Shouldn't it be calling the function disassembled in frame 0? What am I misunderstanding?

This is x64 assembly generated from GCC 4.8 compiling C++ code.

Comment: What's the instruction before the `test`?  The call frame will point to the instruction _after_ the call instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I misunderstanding?

On `x86` (and `x86_64`), the `CALL` instruction pushes the address of the *next* instruction onto stack, and jumps to the called function.

When you go `up`, the current instruction is the one that will be executed after the frame you just stepped up from returns.

Do `x/i $pc-5` if you want to see the actual `CALL` (note: the `-5` works for most, but not all `CALL`s. See Peter Cordes comment below).

Comment: Makes sense. Yes, you are right. Before each of these is the callq command, I just didn't realize it. Thank you!

Comment: or `x/i $pc - 2` if it was an indirect `call *%reg` or `-3` if it needed a REX prefix.  Or `-6` if it was memory-indirect with a RIP-relative addressing mode like `call *funcptr(%rip)`.  You can't in general / uniquely disassemble backwards in x86 machine code, but if you're inside a function in non-obfuscated machine code, GDB can just start at the top of the function.  So use `layout asm` or `layout reg` and you can scroll upward.